# How to use a dictionary that's been declared and filled in another file in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, import

I am having trouble trying to import a dictionary object that I have declared and filled with key,value pairs in another Python file.

A bit of background -- I am working with accessing the Reddit API and then filling a dictionary with subreddit names and a score I have given them, based off of Reddit comments that have been retrieved. My main goal with importing the dictionary is in order to find a way to work with said dictionary of data, to mess around with, without having to make repeated calls to the API and having to wait to keep refilling the dictionary each time I want to test if it runs.

At the moment, I have looked around the internet and other questions on StackOverflow about importing just a dictionary object from another file and class and I keep getting the same error where it says that the 'module' object has no attribute. Please see my example below:

```
from subreddit_score import main
    # the dictionary obj that I wish to use in subreddit_score.py is called top_five
    d = subreddit_score.top_five
```

I'm unsure as to why this is, so if someone would be able to help me I would greatly appreciate it.

Also: if there is a better way to do this, I would also appreciate any input. But I am mainly just asking for a way to import a dictionary variable.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Traceback error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tester.py", line 8, in <module>
    d = subreddit_score.top_five
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'top_five'`

**subreddit_score.py**

```
def main(): 
# fetchRedditData() returns a dictionary
   top_five = fetchRedditData()
```

Comment: Seeing the specific traceback/error message could be helpful but are you doing `import subreddit_sentiment` somewhere (it's just not in the code example you gave)?

Comment: my mistake, I will edit the original question with the traceback error.

Comment: youre trying to call a method on the python file, I think you intended to call it on an object, which you don't have because there is no class in the subreddit_score.py file. Try just using d = main() instead and have your function return the dictionary. also maybe rename the main() function to something more descriptive like get_subreddit_data_dictionary() or whatever

Comment: To clarify, what does `main()` do? Is it _just_ to initialise this variable? Or does it do other stuff too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from subreddit_score import main
# the dictionary obj that I wish to use in subreddit_score.py is called top_five
d = subreddit_score.top_five
```

You're getting the "'module' object has no attribute" error because you are trying to get the value of top_five but it's in a function, not a member of the module which could be accessed from anywhere.

To fix this, you could either change the main() function you have into a getter type object (also, you probably should name this function something other than main)

```
def main():
    # fetchRedditData() returns a dictionary
    top_five = fetchRedditData
    return top_five
```

Or if you want to access the dictionary as a member object, you could just make it global within the file, but I would recommend against this as it is poor design,

Answer (score 0):

`top_five` is local to the function `main` in your `subreddit_score` module. Because it's not in the module scope, you cannot access it as though it was - in a similar way, you won't be able to access it from other functions in the same module.

The quickest fix to this, would be to just make it a global in the module, although this is likely not the best design:

```
top_five = None

def main():
    global top_five
    top_five = fetchRedditData()
```

Now you can access `top_five` from another module that imports this module, but you're temporally coupled to having run `main` first.